# Use function keys for pasting specific text

Tags: windows-7, windows, string, function-keys

I want to assign some text to F keys on Windows 7.

For example, I want to press <kbd>F5</kbd> to paste "000", or press <kbd>F6</kbd> to paste ".00 US Dollars".

It would be appreciated if anyone can help me (a piece of software or code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

You can then edit the default script to add:

```
F5::Send 000
F6::Send .00 US Dollars
```