# Is there any program that can let me assign something to specific keys?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, clipboard

I want to be able to assign text (like copy paste) to each of my numpad keys (like i put in a word for numpad 1, another word for numpad 2, etc and when i click those numpad buttons, the word i need would be pasted in).

Comment: Autohotkey can assign various macros and hotkey combinations to any  key combination you like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best copy and paste software for windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/126967/best-copy-and-paste-software-for-windows)

Comment: @techie007 - I almost always agree with your dupe suggestions, but I think this one is dif. in that assigning keys TO cut and past vs a best cut and past method. Although, I am sure there are many dupe candidates for Autohotkey set ups.

Comment: possible duplicate of [function keys for paste specific text](http://superuser.com/questions/476147/function-keys-for-paste-specific-text)

Answer (score 1):

Use AutoHotkey, it allow you to bind macros to any keys.

www.autohotkey.com

You can assign a macro to paste your desired text to each key.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it exactly? It's really confusing.

Comment: The very first time I used it, was following this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UD_mry_DN-s , take a try.

Comment: Ok I get how to use it but the numpad keys won't work. I put in ::Numpad1::Test and instead of clicking only 1 on numpad to make "Test" appear, I have to actually type out Numpad1. Do you know how to get it to work?

Comment: Check if NumLock is On, http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Comment: Yeah it's on but it still isn't working.

Comment: AutoHotkey is a very powerful tool, but a bit complicated on the start. 

Try this:
`Numpad1::` and on the next line, `Send Test`